# Accessing an item inside an array

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, json.net

Please see the JSON below, which I have validated using https://jsonlint.com/:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 3,
        "count": 3
    },
    "data": [{
            "id": "1",
            "MoreInformation": {
                "id2": "22"
            },
            "type": "Person"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "MoreInformation": {
                "id2": "42"
            },
            "type": "Person"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "MoreInformation": {
                "id2": "99"
            },
            "type": "Person"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please see the code below:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim json As String = "{""meta"": {""limit"": 2,""count"": 2},""data"": [{""id"": ""1"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""22""},""type"": ""Person""},{""id"": ""2"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""42""},""type"": ""Person""},{""id"": ""3"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""99""},""type"": ""Person""}]}"
        Dim jo As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim a As JArray = CType(jo("data"), JArray)
        Dim list As New List(Of Person)

        For Each item In a.Children()
            Dim itemProperties = item.Children(Of JProperty)()
            Dim person As New Person
            person.id1 = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "id")
            person.id2 = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "id2")
            list.Add(person)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Person
    Public Property id1
    Public Property id2
End Class
```

I want the output to be a list of three persons.

The problem is with this line:

```
person.id2 = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "id2")
```

It always returns nothing. How can I populate person.id2 with id2 from the JSON?

**Update**

This works:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim json As String = "{""meta"": {""limit"": 2,""count"": 2},""data"": [{""id"": ""1"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""22""},""type"": ""Person""},{""id"": ""2"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""42""},""type"": ""Person""},{""id"": ""3"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""99""},""type"": ""Person""}]}"
        Dim jo As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
        Dim a As JArray = CType(jo("data"), JArray)
        Dim list As List(Of Person) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Person))(a.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("got here")
    End Sub
```

providing I change the classes to this:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property id
    Public Property MoreInformation
End Class

Public Class MoreInformation
    Public Property id2
End Class
```

However, I am still intigured how to get the code in my original post working.

Comment: Look at your data and look at where in the hierarchy the `id` and `id2` attributes are located. They aren't on the same level so how could your VB code that treats them like they are possibly work? It is the `MoreInformation` attribute that is at the same level as `id` so you obviously need to get that value first, then get the `id2` value from inside it.

Comment: By the way, don't create the object first and then set the properties separately. Do it in one go using an object initialiser. Doing so means that you need no local variable, so you can add the object to the list in the same line, e.g. `list.Add(New Person With {.id1 = ..., .id2 = ...})`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, please see the update to my original post. Is that what you mean? If not then could you post an answer?

Comment: Please put some thought into what I said. If you can get the value of `id` then you can get the value of `MoreInformation` so do that. Once you have that value, look inside it to see how to get `id2`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, that is what I have been trying to do for the last 8 hours and hence the reason for the question.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of your trying to get `MoreInformation` in the question. Like I said, it is a sibling of `id` so you can get its value the same way. Once you have that value then you can get something from within it. I won't be contributing further until I see evidence of your doing what I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you want, but I tried like the code below.

```
 Try

         Dim json As String = "{""meta"": {""limit"": 2,""count"": 2},""data"": [{""id"": ""1"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""22""},""type"": ""Person""},{""id"": ""2"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""42""},""type"": ""Person""},{""id"": ""3"",""MoreInformation"": {""id2"": ""99""},""type"": ""Person""}]}"
         Dim jo As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
         Dim a As JArray = CType(jo("data"), JArray)
         Dim list As New List(Of Person)

         For Each item In a.Children()
            Dim itemProperties = item.Children(Of JProperty)()
            Dim itemProperties2 = item.SelectToken("MoreInformation").Children(Of JProperty)()

            Dim person As New Person
            person.id1 = itemProperties.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "id")
            person.id2 = itemProperties2.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "id2")
            list.Add(person)
         Next

         For Each item In list

            Debug.WriteLine("id1:" & item.id1.ToString & " id2:" & item.id2.ToString)

         Next
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.ToString)
      End Try
```

Comment: Yes it is thanks.  I am curious about jmcilhinneys comment about doing it all in one line though.